# Adobe Illustrator pictures to be played on a scoreboard with the dimensions of 1280 x 424

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, resolution, video

Ok, I want to make a video for a wedding, to be played on a stadium scoreboard.  The scoreboard's dimensions are `1280 x 424`.  I was told to make my images this size and make a DVD in either `.wmv` or `.mov`.

**My issue**

How do I make the pictures that I have made with Illustrator, and make a video with them? Can I make the video's dimensions fit the scoreboard?

FYI, I have been using illustrator for 2 years, but nothing in this capacity.

Comment: Illustrator certainly isn't right for making videos..

Comment: That's my question... why are you using Illustrator for video?

Comment: My assumption would be that they are just making images in Illustrator and then doing some of of slideshow movie, but further clarification would be nice.

Comment: Sorry, yes,  We are just making the pictures in illustrator, and then going to make a slideshow using them.  My issue is exporting the pictures with a high enough resolution that it is going to look fine on the big scoreboard.  The reason I am doing this, is the guy in charge said we could put pictures on the scoreboard if we formatted them to fit ourselves.  I am just basically putting black around the photos, or two per slide so the pictures will not be stretched in the weird dimensions.  Am I doing this wrong?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Just make your artboard(s) 1280x424 and place your images on that artboard. When ready Save for web and use the "Clip to Artboard" option in the Save for Web window.

You're over-thinking this. There is absolutely nothing special about the fact that the images will be for video. Simply create the images to size and save them.

Once you have your images saved, you'll need some other application to create a .mov or .wmv slideshow. Illustrator has no functionality to create video. The best you can do with Illustrator is an .swf file.

You can use Photoshop Extended and simply stack the layers and create a frame animation with the timing set as you want. Then use `File > Export > Render to Video` to create the video.